# Is there a way to use "js-yaml" to add one YAML file to another YAML file in nodejs unix environment

Tags: node.js, shell, unix, yaml

I have two YAML files. I want to add the second YAML file inside first YAML file using "js-yaml". Basically my first YAML file continues to grow by adding multiple YAML files.

I have tried to add the new file directly to first YAML file, and it has added, but when I try it again, it is replacing the current data, not adding it:

```
try {
  var filename = path.join(__dirname, "first.yaml"),
    contents = fs.readFileSync(filename, "utf8"),
    first = yaml.load(contents);

  var filename2 = path.join(__dirname, "second.yaml"),
    contents2 = fs.readFileSync(filename2, "utf8"),
    second = yaml.load(contents2);

  var fruits = first.fruits ;
  var newfruits = second.fruits;
  first.fruits= newfruits;

  console.log(util.inspect(first, false, 10, true));
  fs.writeFile("first.yaml", yaml.dump(first), "utf8", err => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
```

the above code is replacing fruits always not adding it. I want to stack it when ever I want it to add.

Comment: You are overwriting `first.fruits` every time. You should probably test that it is an array, and if it is, append `channel2` (whatever that is) to that array, and if it is not, create an array with one element `channel2`.

Comment: it is not an array, is there a way to add data to yaml using js-yaml if it is not an array but object

Comment: Without seeing your YAML it is guess what you are trying to achieve and what you are doing wrong. Please edit your post to include that information (and make sure the post  stays a single coherent whole, no "**UPDATE** or similar sections).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I had a look on you code and there is not much to do to obtain the desired result.

Use:

```
first = first + second;
```

or:

```
first = second;
```